# Find a random unanswered question

Tags: discussion, search, unanswered-questions, navigation

I'd like to find a random unanswered question on my site.  I know of the 'Unanswered' tab on the All Questions page (`/questions`), but that sorts by votes.  Is there a way to get it to sort randomly?

Someone else suggested to me that they'd periodically like to look at a random set of old unanswered questions.  Currently, when going to that page, they'll always see the same ones.  Is there a way to be presented with random ones to look at?

Comment: There isn't a native random post feature, but there is a cool website [Dice Stack - Find a random question](https://stackapps.com/q/1643) on Stack Apps

Comment: I think this would be a useful feature to have. No need to make it too complicated, just a "sort by random" or "randomize" button in the unanswered questions section. Possibly even just a button that takes you to a random question with one of your tags (or not). I currently access SE through a bookmarked link, though I like the idea of being able to change that link to one which opens a random unanswered question (wikipedia has similar functionality with a random page) so on entry to the site I get exposed to something new, especially if I've already read through recent "new" questions.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023563 but enter a new seed on every run

Comment: You could always just create a filtered search for tags you're interested in and go to a random page on it. There may even be a way to only show unanswered questions using `isanswered`.